# User ID creation on java clusetered application

Tags: java, cluster-computing, distributed

What is the best strategy when building a user creation module which is deployed in multiple clusters?

Basically, want to avoid different user from being picking same username, username is unique ID, as same username request can be triggered to different cluster at same time.

Each creation will search for the existence of requested username.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

For unique user id you can use [UUID](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) class and its method [randomUUID()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()). This class is the answer for this specific need. As for user name One of the solutions would be to have a single DB or DB table for all clusters, so the check would be done against the same source by all clusters and synchronization issues could be dealt with on transaction level, and you can define username column as Unique. Another idea is that you have a webservice that is hosted on a single server possibly outside of your cluster. This service will be responsible for verifying and writing User names and all your clusters will use this service. It will be this service responsibility to deal with concurrency issues. The most primitive solution of course to make it sequential i.e. one request at the time. Sometimes it could be good enough. If not there are other techniques with better performance but more complex

Comment: Thanks Micheal for details explanation. Actually my problem exist within application layer because data store is LDAP. As username is picked up by user i want to make that unique withing the application layer. Actually, its currently hosted as single node SOAP service and due to load it needs to be distributed.

Comment: It seems that the suggested solution still would apply for application layer unless I misunderstood you. If you have a single table for all clusters where your app runs it will provide the solution the same as remote Web service to which any of your cluster would call to verify that a user name is valid or not. If that doesn't resolve your problem please clarify why and I will try to help you

Comment: Micheal appreciate your comment. As its LDAP username is not unique as RDBM table column. So uniqueness is maintain at Application layer. Before each creation there is a check for validity. But my concern is, say two cluster check validity and then both going to create same username concurrently. So, what is the best way to handle this at application layer?

Comment: If you can't change username column to unique in DB then your validity check can be restricted to take one validation request at the time. This way to near simultaneous request still will be processed sequentially. That will solve your problem.